# What is a direct product of two Markov process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

In a paper I'm reading it's written:

Let $(\zeta _t,P_{(i,j)})$ be the direct product process taking value in $\mathbb Z^d\times \mathbb Z^d$ of two copie of the Markov process $(\xi_t,P_i)$ which has probability transition $$P_{t}^{(2)}((i,j),(k,l))=P_t(i,k)P_t(j,l).$$
What does it mean ? That $$\zeta _t=\xi^1_t\xi^2_t$$
s.t. $\xi_i$ is a Markov process refer to $P_i$ ?

Comment: No, $\zeta_t \neq \xi_t^1 \xi_t^2$. For one, $\zeta_t$ has dimension $2d$.  $\zeta_t$ is just the state of two Markov processes at time $t$. So, for example, $\mathbb{P}(\zeta_t = (i,j)) = \mathbb{P}(\xi_t^{(1)} = i, ~ \xi_t^{(2)} = j) = \mathbb{P}(\xi_t^{(1)} = i) \mathbb{P}(\xi_t^{(2)} = j)$. Something that might confuse you is the definition you give for $P_t^{(2)}(\cdot,\cdot)$. In that definition you need to interpret $(i,j) \in \mathbb{Z}^d \times \mathbb{Z}^d$, where $i,j \in \mathbb{Z}^d$.

Comment: Indeed, under $P_{(i,j)}$, $\zeta_t=(\xi^1_t,\xi^2_t)$ where $\xi^1$ and $\xi^2$ are two independent copies of $\xi$ starting from $\xi^1_0=i$ and $\xi^2_0=j$ respectively.

Comment: @Did: Thank you, I see better.

Comment: @Ritz: Thanks to Did, I understand well your answer (it was not clear at the beginning). Thank you

Comment: @user330587 Great.